# How do non-interactive programs get the permission to edit files in /etc

Tags: linux, python, monit

I'm writing a program in python that needs to edit some files in /etc.  Some system some its own.  How do I get those permissions from within the program itself without running sudo as the program will be non-interactive?

Not sure yet where I'm going to autostart my program but I will likely use monit or similar for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to run the program itself as root, thereby having permission to files in /etc.

Comment: okay.  And if I don't want to run as root because of security concerns?  I only need access to certain files and directories.  Running as root seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 1):

There are of course two possibilities:

1. decrease the permissions of the files to a level the user can access
2. increase the permissions the modifying app is having

regarding 1)
You can try to add additional rights via ACLs (I would heavily discourage changing the UNIX permissions, lots of programs have expectations and they will be changed with the next update etc.).

```
setfacl -m "u:auto_user:rw" /etc/passwd
```

(You need to have extended ACLs enabled on this filesystem)

With this method you risk, that these access rights are being used by another program.
For example: if you add the apache user to allow modifying /etc/passwd, anyone who gains control of the apache user can now tamper with this file. User accounts are usually less heavily hardened than root level access.

regarding 2)
You elevate the rights to access this file. You can do this either with sudo and the NOPASSWD variable, but you need to be careful to set the right access rights. Somthing like

```
  auto_user = NOPASSWD: /bin/sed ... /etc/passwd
```

is not safe (sed can spawn shells)!
The best solution would be to write a specialised program, which a) filters input and b) does exactly what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Any program (whether interactive, like `vi`, or non-interactive, like `sed`) has an effective user ID (EUID) that the system uses to decide what files it can access, and what operations it can perform (read, write and/or execute).  (There's also a set of group IDs that are used for the same purposes if the EUID is different from the owner of the file.  And if neither EUID nor any GID matches, then access is controlled by the "Other" permission bits.)

If your program runs as `root` (EUID 0) then it can access anything that can be accessed at all, although things can still be made read-only.  (Of course, `root` can change the permission of such things, so read-only is only advisory for `root`.)

One common way to permit access to some users or programs, without allowing access to all, is to change the owner of the file to a special user created for that purpose.  For example, people often make a web administrator or DB administrator user that can edit appropriate config files.

In your case, you could create a special user, change the owner of the files in `/etc` that should be accessible, and then run your program as that user by using `su`.

Another approach is to move the editable files somewhere else, and put symbolic links to that place in `/etc`.

However you do it, you must be sure that the users / UIDs / GIDs that can access the files are trusted with whatever the functionality is.  For example, you wouldn't want non-root users to be able to edit the password file, because they can easily obtain root privileges.

Comment: Your solution sounds like what I need.  I can su my program from monit.  I don't have a linux box in front of me but I think a normal permission for a system file in /etc would be something like r-w/r--/r--  assuming thats the case then if I change owners and set the permissions to r-w/r-w/r-- will anything break?

Comment: You should be OK as far as breakage goes -- files in `/etc` aren't edited that often.  As long as the owner or group of the file matches the EUID / GID of your program, and the corresponding permission allows writing, your program should be able to do what it needs.
One thing to consider carefully, though, is what a malicious person could do if they got access to that file.  If your changes somehow permit a bad guy to edit the file, can he use that access to escalate his privileges on the system somehow?  Is that computer trusted by another computer, which could be attacked?  Etc.

Comment: Thats precisely the point what I want to limit access.  Sounds like I'm on the right track with oyur idea.  Will test in a few days as I have to get a demo going for the end of the week.To put it in context what I want to do is have a user insert a usb key which contains configuration files which are copied to the filesystem.  Then the system will reboot.  One of those files will be /etc/network/interfaces.  This should allow my user to configure the embedded system headless.